# How to get results of a function by calling it within a class in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object

I am not familiar with classes and object oriented coding in python and I am trying to write a class that collects different functions I defined previously. As below, without a class structure I can get my parameters 'params' by just calling the function mymin(), params = mymin(x, y, z) that will be used in the function myresults later.

My issue, how can I get the parameters params in a class structure? One way is to call the function mymin() inside the function myresults(). However I need to call the two functions separately as at the bottom of the code and I don't want to run again the mymin() function inside the myresults().

```
class myClass():

      def mymin(self, x, y, z):
          params = minfunction()
          return params[0]

      params = mymin(x, y, z)

      def myresults(self, x):
          params_new = params[:, np.newaxis]
          return otherfunction(params_new, x)
```

I need to call the functions in the following way.

```
mycalling = myClass()
mycalling.mymin(x, y, z)
mycalling.myresults(x)
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not the indentation. This is a text version of part of the original code. My problem is how to call a function within a class.

Comment: `fmin_tnc()` is undefined -as is `otherfunction` as are `x,y,z` in the line `params = mymin(x, y, z)`

Comment: `params = mymin(x, y, z)` needs parameters provided - what are x,y,z ? where do they come from?

Comment: currently `params` is an class attribute - and you get NameErrors on it -you provide `x,y,z` to `mymin` - do you want to do something like `self.params = params[0]` inside  `mymin`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks a lot. fmin_tnc() and otherfunction() are undefined because this is part of a code. I didn't want to write the entire code. My question is if it is possible to call get parameters by calling a function inside a class.

Comment: @PatrickArtner if I insert self.params inside mymin() how the function myresults() can get the params from mymin()? This is my issue